# Getting exception on kinesis when try to put records

Tags: amazon-kinesis

I am following the codes provided by AWS to write some data to kinesis from spark RDD as folllow:

```
int colname=0;

for (String item: items)
{
    String key=String.valueOf(colname);
    colname++;

    ByteBuffer data = ByteBuffer.wrap(item.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    // doesn't block       

    System.out.println(String.format("Putting the item=[%s] with key=[%s]",item,key));
    PutRecordsRequestEntry putRecordsRequestEntry = new PutRecordsRequestEntry();
    putRecordsRequestEntry.setData(data);
    putRecordsRequestEntry.setPartitionKey(key);
    putRecordsRequestEntryList.add(putRecordsRequestEntry);


}


}

putRecordsRequest.setRecords(putRecordsRequestEntryList);
PutRecordsResult putRecordsResult = kinesisClient.putRecords(putRecordsRequest);
```

The parts of the code I am using for authorization is as foolow:

```
ClientConfiguration config=new ClientConfiguration().withMaxErrorRetry(30)
                        .withConnectionTimeout(100*1000).withSocketTimeout(100*1000);


BasicAWSCredentials basicAWSCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("****", "****");
AmazonKinesis kinesisClient = AmazonKinesisClientBuilder.standard()//.withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(basicAWSCredentials))
               .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1).withClientConfiguration(config).build();
```

Since, I am running on EMR, I don't use AWS credentials, However, I am getting exception in my spark:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 35 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 35.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 53, ip-172-31-27-87.ec2.internal, executor 9): com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.model.AmazonKinesisException: 1 validation error detected: Value '[PutRecordsRequestEntry(data=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=9 cap=9], explicitHashKey=null, partitionKey=0), PutRecordsRequestEntry(data=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=6 cap=6], explicitHashKey=null,com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.model.AmazonKinesisException: 1 validation error detected: Value '[PutRecordsRequestEntry(data=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=9 cap=9], explicitHashKey=null, partitionKey=0), partitionKey=1), PutRecordsRequestEntry(data=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=8 cap=8], explicitHashKey=null, partitionKey=2), PutRecordsRequestEntry(data=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=10 cap=10], explicitHashKey=null, partitionKey=3), PutRecordsRequestEntry(data=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=11 cap=11], explicitHashKey=null, partitionKey=4), PutRecordsRequestEntry(data=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=11 cap=11], explicitHashKey=null, partitionKey=5), PutRecordsRequestEntry(data=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=6 cap=6], explicitHashKey=null, partitionKey=6), PutRecordsRequestEntry(data=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=13 cap=13], explicitHashKey=null, partitionKey=7), PutRecordsRequestEntry(data=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=11 cap=11], explicitHashKey=null, partitionKey=8),
```

Comment: It seems that your kinesisClient is not initialised properly or you are not authorised to write to kinesis.

Comment: I have posted the code which I am using for client initialisation as well.

Comment: Make sure that proper role is attached to your emr and that role has kinesis policy.

Comment: Actually, I can write to EMR by using another codes which are using KCL but not through above codes so there should be no issues with policies.

Comment: Roles and policies matters always so please read about them for your account.